# Getting File count from a Document Library folder using SharePoint Designer

Tags: document-library, designer-workflow

I have a SharePoint list and have written a workflow when an item gets created or changed. In this workflow, is there a way to check or get the count of files from a specific folder in a Document Library?

I would want to display certain text in the email that gets triggered from the workflow based on if any files exists in that folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write in the workflow to get the file count from a document library through a series of actions in the workflow
follow the steps

1. Open the workflow in designer
2. Follow the action which I specified in the below screen shots

[image]

3. check what need to do in action 1 & Action 2 in below pics

[image]

[image]

[image]

4. Finally you will get file count in last action in item count workflow variable. You can keep your condition using itemcount variable in workflow.

Please check and let me know if you have any queries.. !